# Missing entitlements file

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm suddenly getting two warnings in XCODE:

```
/Users/me/Documents/Misc IOS DEV/myAPP/myAPP.xcodeproj Missing entitlements file for target myAPPUITests: "/var/folders/wb/9dsv1b5j53n8qbwmbh49qf9m0000gn/T/Entitlements.plist-gmk"

/Users/me/Documents/Misc IOS DEV/myAPP/myAPP.xcodeproj Missing entitlements file for target myAPPUITests: "/var/folders/wb/9dsv1b5j53n8qbwmbh49qf9m0000gn/T/Entitlements.plist-pCm"
```

Anyone have any idea what these are and how I can remove the warnings? Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

Ok go to your target build settings and go to signing section
in code signing entitlements delete the path for entitlements
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Restarting Xcode fixed the issue for me.

The folder those warnings reference is a per-user temporary file/folder cache. If restarting Xcode doesn't fix the issue, I'd suggest restarting OSX.

Answer (score 3):

Product > Clean has worked for me multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

By assigning your Apple Developer ID to the **Code Signing Identity** section of the Build settings, this should clear up the warning messages.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project> Target > Build Settings > Signing

Here in 'CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS', put your path.

$(SRCROOT)/ProjectName/PathToFolder/AnotherFolder/YourProject.entitlements

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this, the same happened to me with a new OSX project in the XCode 7.2.

In my case, I needed to add my device to my Developer account at https://developer.apple.com, and also create Provisioning Profile for the app.

I added my device by hand using the UUID from the 'Identifier' value in XCode's Devices Window.

I let XCode create the Provisioning Profile, by using the Organizer Window, selecting my App, and then clicking the 'Export ...' button and choosing 'Export a Development-signed Application'.

That cleared up the errors on the next build.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, you can opt to not sign your software (for e.g. local builds, simply playing around).

Select your project in the tree view (item at the top), then in the main window, select "Build Settings", navigate to the section "Code Signing", which is where the error occurs ("code signing entitlements").
Then, for "Code Signing Entity", simply select "Don't Code Sign".

Just remember to update this when you do need to sign your app.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your Project Targets, select Capabilities tab, and look for an issue on one of the enabled item. Click on the fix button. Another way to do this also by going to the Build Settings, search for Code Signing Entitlements, make sure it shows "yourProjectModule/EntitlementName.entitlements"

Answer (score 0):

If you've enabled "Automatically manage signing" for your target(s), then go to your target settings, choose the "Signing & Capabilities" tab, and uncheck and then re-check "Automatically manage signing". It worked for me.